# Can I store an `impl Future` as a concrete type?

Tags: rust, async-await, future, rust-tokio

`tokio::net::TcpStream::connect` is an async function, meaning it returns an existential type, `impl Future`. I would like to store a `Vec` of these futures in a struct. I've found many questions where someone wants to store multiple *different* `impl Future`s in a list, but I only want to store the return type of one. I feel like this should be possible without `Box<dyn Future>` as I am really only storing a single concrete type, but I cannot figure out how without getting `found opaque type` errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with the nightly feature `min_type_alias_impl_trait`. The trick is to create a type alias, and a dummy function from which the compiler can infer a defining use.

```rust
#![feature(min_type_alias_impl_trait)]

use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use core::future::Future;

type TcpStreamConnectFut = impl Future<Output = std::io::Result<TcpStream>>;

fn __tcp_stream_connect_defining_use() -> TcpStreamConnectFut  {
    TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080")
}

struct Foo {
    connection_futs: Vec<TcpStreamConnectFut>,
}
```

This compiles, but does not work as expected:

```rust
impl Foo {
    fn push(&mut self) {
        self.connection_futs.push(TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080"));
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:18:35
    |
6   | type TcpStreamConnectFut = impl Future<Output = std::io::Result<TcpStream>>;
    |                            ------------------------------------------------ the expected opaque type
...
18  |         self.connection_futs.push(TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080"));
    |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found a different opaque type
    |
    = note: while checking the return type of the `async fn`
    = note: expected opaque type `impl Future` (opaque type at <src/lib.rs:6:28>)
               found opaque type `impl Future` (opaque type at </playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.7.1/src/net/tcp/stream.rs:111:56>)
    = help: consider `await`ing on both `Future`s
    = note: distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque types
```

Using the dummy function we created *does* work:

```rust
impl Foo {
    fn push(&mut self) {
        self.connection_futs.push(__tcp_stream_connect_defining_use());
    }
}
```

So we can just create wrapper functions:

```rust
fn tcp_stream_connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(addr: A) -> TcpStreamConnectFut  {
    TcpStream::connect(addr)
}
```

Except...

```
error: type parameter `A` is part of concrete type but not used in parameter list for the `impl Trait` type alias
  --> src/main.rs:9:74
   |
9  |   fn tcp_stream_connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(addr: A) -> TcpStreamConnectFut  {
   |  __________________________________________________________________________^
10 | |     TcpStream::connect(addr)
11 | | }
   | |_^
```

We could just use `String` or `&'static str`, and the entire thing compiles:

```rust
type TcpStreamConnectFut = impl Future<Output = std::io::Result<TcpStream>>;

fn tcp_stream_connect(addr: &'static str) -> TcpStreamConnectFut  {
    TcpStream::connect(addr)
}

struct Foo {
    connection_futs: Vec<TcpStreamConnectFut>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn push(&mut self) {
        self.connection_futs.push(tcp_stream_connect("..."));
    }
}
```

You can also add a generic parameter to the type alias itself, but that probably doesn't make sense in this case:

```rust
type TcpStreamConnectFut<A> = impl Future<Output = std::io::Result<TcpStream>>;

fn tcp_stream_connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(addr: A) -> TcpStreamConnectFut<A>  {
    TcpStream::connect(addr)
}

struct Foo {
    connection_futs: Vec<TcpStreamConnectFut<&'static str>>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn push(&mut self) {
        self.connection_futs.push(tcp_stream_connect("..."));
    }
}
```

So it *is* possible, but there are a couple of restrictions. I'm not sure how many of these are bugs, and how much of it is intentional behavior. There has been discussion about a `typeof` operator to make this easier, but this is what we've got at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a good old `Vec`, just like that:

```rust
use core::future::Future;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

fn just_vec() -> Vec<impl Future<Output = std::io::Result<TcpStream>>> {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    
    // connect to several streams
    v.push(TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080"));
    v.push(TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.2:8080"));
    
    v
}
```

However, it gets more tricky if you want to store it in a struct, because unlike above, where concrete type can be inferred, you need to be more explicit with structs.

One stable way to do this, is to use a generic struct. This actually very similar to storing a closure (where you don't have a concrete type either).

```rust
use core::future::Future;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;

struct Foo<T> {
    connections: Vec<T>,
}
/// This is just like any other vec-wrapper
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            connections: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
    pub fn push(&mut self, conn: T) {
        self.connections.push(conn);
    }
}
/// Some more specific functios that actually need the Future
impl<T> Foo<T> where T: Future<Output = std::io::Result<TcpStream>> {
    pub async fn broadcast(self, data: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        for stream in self.connections {
            stream.await?.write_all(data).await?
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

async fn with_struct() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut foo = Foo::new();
    
    // connect to several streams
    foo.push(TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080"));
    foo.push(TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.2:8080"));
    
    // Do something with the connections
    foo.broadcast(&[1,2,3]).await
}
```

Comment: Yep, this works too, by pushing the work out to a place the type can be inferred by the compiler. It doesn't work for all cases though.